# How to get values from vlookup 2042 error vba Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vba, range, vlookup

```
Option Explicit

Sub ActivityMatching()

Dim wsToLook As Worksheet
Set wsToLook = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataOra")
Dim rngToLook As Range
Set rngToLook = wsToLook.Range("A2:H1000")

Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim iCell As Range
Dim rngToInsert As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim whatToFind As Variant

    With wsMain

        .Range("A1:M1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Dialer Attempt"
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Set rngToInsert = .Range("K2:K" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        For Each iCell In rngToInsert
            whatToFind = iCell.Offset(, -10).Value
            iCell.Value = Application.VLOOKUP(CLng(whatToFind), rngToLook, 7, False)
        Next iCell

    End With

End Sub
```

Sheet "Sheet2" column A- the key, column K where I want to put the values
Sheet "DataOra" column A the key, column G the values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfEiV.png)
I received 2042 error. All the values are #N/A

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzN8r.jpg)

Comment: That's a data issue, rather than a code one per se. Are  you sure you're looking at the right column(s) and that the values actually are stored as numbers in the first column of the lookup table?

Comment: @Rory   https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfEiV.png     can you help me, please?
              https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzN8r.jpg

Comment: There are no visible matches based on your pictures. Does an actual vlookup formula in the cell return anything other than an error?

Comment: @Rory doesn't return anything... If I use VLOOKUP without VBA it's ok. I got all the values... I get 2042 error on iCell for range... I don't know why....

Comment: What is the working cell formula?

Comment: =VLOOKUP(A496;DataOra!A:G;7;0)

Comment: Then try removing the `CLng()` function from your code.

Comment: Nop, the same... I try to make VLOOKUP with filter between 2 sheets. I m a newbie on VBA, and I didn't find anything on internet for dynamic range...

Comment: If your formula is `=VLOOKUP(A496;DataOra!A2:G1000;7;0)` does it work?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work :(

Comment: That suggests you have just set the lookup table range too small.

Comment: Yes, actually i improved the range and it's works! TY